# 500 Internal Server Error Docker Hosted ASP.Net MVC web app (RESOLVED)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, docker, iis

We have a ASP.Net MVC app and which works fine when we run even locally in debug mode from Visual Studio.
We have 4 Class library projects and one web api project. Following is my docker file:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8 AS build
WORKDIR /app

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.sln .
COPY xxxxx/*.csproj ./xxxxx/
COPY yyyyyy/*.csproj ./yyyyy/
# copy everything else and build app
COPY xxxxx/ ./xxxxx/
COPY yyyyy/ ./yyyyy/
RUN nuget restore

WORKDIR /app/GetThree
RUN msbuild /p:Configuration=Release

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8 AS runtime
WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot
COPY --from=build /app/xxxxx/. ./
```

Once I build the docker file, everything compiles properly and build is successful also (all Nuget packages are restored) and I am able to create the container as well. But unfortunately whenever I try to browse to my web-app (I got the IP address of the container as this is windows base) but unfortunately I get HTTP 500 internal server error immediately. I have made sure that the HTTPERROR section is set for detailed error message.

As soon as I navigate to the ip address I get this 500 error and unfortunately not much is availble in the logs (Application or System) which will help me as to what the issue could be.  Any help?

Following is the command I use to build and run the container:

```
docker build -f .\GetThree\Dockerfile -t threecms/cmsdocker:1.0 
docker run --name threecms --rm -it -p 8100:80 threecms/cmsdocker:1.0
```

To browse the site I get the IP Address (using docker exec threecms ipconfig) and I browse it using: http://ipadress:8100

UPDATE 1:-

I created one more image from above image using following dockerfile ( urlrewrite is the URLREWRITE module install script)

```
FROM threecms/cmsdocker:1.0
WORKDIR C:/
Copy urlrewrite.ps1/ .
RUN "Powershell ./urlrewrite.ps1"

RUN Install-WindowsFeature Web-Mgmt-Service; \

New-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\software\microsoft\WebManagement\Server -Name EnableRemoteManagement -Value 1 -Force; \

Set-Service -Name wmsvc -StartupType automatic;
```

URL REWRITE PS1 script:

```
New-Item c:/msi -ItemType Directory
Invoke-WebRequest 'http://download.microsoft.com/download/C/F/F/CFF3A0B8-99D4-41A2-AE1A-496C08BEB904/WebPlatformInstaller_amd64_en-US.msi' -OutFile c:/msi/WebPlatformInstaller_amd64_en-US.msi
Start-Process 'c:/msi/WebPlatformInstaller_amd64_en-US.msi' '/qn' -PassThru | Wait-Process
cd 'C:/Program Files/Microsoft/Web Platform Installer'; .\WebpiCmd.exe /Install /Products:'UrlRewrite2,ARRv3_0' /AcceptEULA /Log:c:/msi/WebpiCmd.log
```

Then I ran the container using following command:-

```
docker run --name threecms2 -d cmswindfeature/cmswinfeature:3.0
```

And now whenever I got to my application from browser it gives me the actual error msg which is:

```
Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\App_Data\TEMP\PluginCache\umbraco-plugins.373F7AAE388A.hash' is denied.
```

UPDATE:-2  RESOLVED

So to Resolve above error I ran the following Powershell script (To add required Permissions) and Boom I was able to access my site and its working now:-

```
$accessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("IIS_IUSRS", "FullControl", "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")
$acl = Get-ACL "C:\inetpub\wwwroot"
$acl.AddAccessRule($accessRule)
Set-ACL -Path "C:\inetpub\wwwroot" -ACLObject $acl
```

Comment: Add the command you use to run the image and check the container logs.

Comment: @Max added both the commands to build and run the image, also whenever I run the docker container logs containerID  command all I get is :   Service 'w3svc' has been stopped

 Service 'w3svc' started

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out from the application pool for the website what is the identity it is running under (by default this is Application Pool Identity) and grant that the correct permissions. normally, it is IIS_IUSRS, you can try the following steps to solve the problem:

Right Click Folder-> go to Security Tab-> Click on Edit-> Click on Add-> Click on Advanced
-> Find Now-> Give Permission to IIS_IUSRS (Full Control)-> Click On OK-> Click On OK->
Click On Full Control in allow-> Click On OK.

Note: If above things are not working then try to give same permission to NETWORK,NETWORK SERVICE Users

Comment: Thank you for your response @samwu but I had resolved this issue and posted the answer in my previous post.